# Android Issue with JSonObect

Tags: java, android, json, android-activity, httprequest

I am having problem with a JsonObject and I can't seem to figure out why.

Here is the Error:

```
03-23 01:19:58.128 11981-12144/com.example.admirmonteiro.login W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <!--this of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
03-23 01:19:58.133 11981-12144/com.example.admirmonteiro.login W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
03-23 01:19:58.134 11981-12144/com.example.admirmonteiro.login W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
03-23 01:19:58.134 11981-12144/com.example.admirmonteiro.login W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
03-23 01:19:58.134 11981-12144/com.example.admirmonteiro.login W/System.err:     at com.example.admirmonteiro.login.signUpActivity$JSONAsyncRegisterTask.postData(signUpActivity.java:225)
03-23 01:19:58.134 11981-12144/com.example.admirmonteiro.login W/System.err:     at com.example.admirmonteiro.login.signUpActivity$JSONAsyncRegisterTask.doInBackground(signUpActivity.java:145)
03-23 01:19:58.134 11981-12144/com.example.admirmonteiro.login W/System.err:     at com.example.admirmonteiro.login.signUpActivity$JSONAsyncRegisterTask.doInBackground(signUpActivity.java:111)
03-23 01:19:58.134 11981-12144/com.example.admirmonteiro.login W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
03-23 01:19:58.134 11981-12144/com.example.admirmonteiro.login W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-23 01:19:58.134 11981-12144/com.example.admirmonteiro.login W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
03-23 01:19:58.134 11981-12144/com.example.admirmonteiro.login W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
03-23 01:19:58.134 11981-12144/com.example.admirmonteiro.login W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
03-23 01:19:58.134 11981-12144/com.example.admirmonteiro.login W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This is my code(Activity)All Im trying to do is send the parameters to be posted on the database :

```
public class signUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean result = false, authenticate = false;
    private static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://eclipsegym.pe.hu/";


     EditText signUpEmail, signUpPassword, firstname, lastname, department;
     Button btn_signUp;
     RequestQueue requestQueue;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        signUpEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signUp_email);
        signUpPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signUp_password);
        firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_firstname);
        lastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_lastname);
        department = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.departmentId);
        btn_signUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());



        btn_signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String firstName =firstname.getText().toString();
                String lastName = lastname.getText().toString();
                String email = signUpEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = signUpPassword.getText().toString();
                String apt = department.getText().toString();
                String userType = "1";
                User registeredData = new User(firstName,lastName,password,email,apt,userType);

                registerUser(registeredData);

            }

        });

    }

    private void registerUser(User user) {

        Log.i("1name",user.firstName);
        Log.i("lname",user.lastName);
        Log.i("apt",user.department);
        Log.i("email",user.email);
        Log.i("pw",user.password);

        if (user.firstName.equals("") || user.lastName.equals("") || user.department.equals("") || user.email.equals("") || user.password.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill in the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (!user.password.equals(user.password)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password and Confirm Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            new JSONAsyncRegisterTask().execute(user.firstName, user.lastName, user.password, user.email,user.department,user.userType, SERVER_ADDRESS);
        }



    }

    private class JSONAsyncRegisterTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(signUpActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Connecting to Server");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Processing Registration!! HOLD ON BROTHER!");
            progressDialog.show();
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

            String urlParameters = null;
            try {
                Log.d("hey", params.toString());
                urlParameters = "firstName=" + URLEncoder.encode(params[0], "UTF-8") +
                        "&lastName=" + URLEncoder.encode(params[1], "UTF-8") +
                        "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(params[2], "UTF-8")+
                        "&email=" + URLEncoder.encode(params[3], "UTF-8") +
                        "&department=" + URLEncoder.encode(params[4], "UTF-8") +
                        "&userType=" + URLEncoder.encode(params[5], "UTF-8")
                ;

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                printIt("i","before post Data");
                result = postData(urlParameters, params[6]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

            progressDialog.cancel();

            if(result){
                Toast.makeText(signUpActivity.this, "Registeration Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registration Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(signUpActivity.this);
                    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Registration Success!");
                    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK...", null);
                    dialogBuilder.show();
                Intent intent =  new Intent(signUpActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registration Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(signUpActivity.this);
                dialogBuilder.setMessage("Registration Failure!");
                dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK...", null);
                dialogBuilder.show();
            }


        }

        public boolean postData(String urlParameters, String strUrl) throws JSONException {

            Log.i("Im Here", "Post Data Method");
            URL url;

            HttpURLConnection connection;
            Log.i("urlLink", strUrl);
            Log.d("urlParams", urlParameters);

            try {
                String link = strUrl + "signup_ac.php";
                Log.d("urlLink", link);
                url = new URL(link);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
                connection.setUseCaches(false);
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(false);

                Log.i("Im Here", "sending stream");

                DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(urlParameters);
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                dataOutputStream.close();

                Log.i("Im Here", "input stream");
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, HTTP.UTF_8),8);
                String line;

                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                    response.append('\r');
                }
                Log.i("data", response.toString());
                bufferedReader.close();
                Log.i("data2", response.toString());

                Log.i("Im Here", "result");

                String result = response.toString();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                Log.i("Im Here", "auth");
                String isAuth = jsonObject.getString("result");

                authenticate = isAuth.equals("true");
            } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return  authenticate;
        }
    }


    public void printIt (String leter ,String value){


        if (leter=="i") {
            Log.i("value:", value);
        }else if(leter=="d"){
            Log.d("d",value);

        }
    }

}
```

I can't seem to figure out why this is the output, I have tried multiple things with the JSON but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my php code that returns the json array with result : true .

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
include "generalUtility.php";
global $UsersTable, $administratorsEmail,$doctorsTable,$mysql_database,$PatientsTable,$connect;
$UsersTabledoctorsID = 0;



$firstName=$_GET["firstName"];
$lastName=$_GET["lastName"];
$email=$_GET["email"];
$password=$_GET["password"];
$department=$_GET["department"];
$userType=$_GET["userType"];

if (isset($firstName,$lastName,$email,$password,$department,$userType)){
    if (!empty($firstName) && !empty($lastName) && !empty($email) && !empty($password) && !empty($department)&& !empty($userType)) {
        $userType = (int) $userType ;
        /** Insert data into database **/
        $encrypted_password = md5($password);
        if (emailValidation($email)) {
            if (doesUserExist($email)) {
                $arr = array('result' => false);
                echo json_encode($arr);
            } else {
                //Queries 
                $sql = "INSERT INTO $mysql_database.$UsersTable (firstName, lastName, password, email,userType)VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$encrypted_password','$email','$userType')";
                $res = mysql_query($sql, $connect) or die(mysql_error());
                if ($res) {
//                    echo " Query ? : UserTable" . $res . " \n";
                    $UsersTabledoctorsID = mysql_insert_id();
                    //echo "Usersdoctors: ".$UsersTabledoctorsID."\n";
                }else{
                    echo "UsersDoctors: No ID \n";

                }
                $sql2 = "INSERT INTO $mysql_database.$doctorsTable (Users_idUser,department)VALUES ('$UsersTabledoctorsID', '$department')";
                $res2 = mysql_query($sql2, $connect) or die(mysql_error());
                if ($res2) {
//                    echo " Query ? : doctor Table" . $res2 . " \n";
                    $doctorsID = mysql_insert_id();
                    //echo "doctors: ".$doctorsID."\n";
                }else{

                    echo "doctors: No ID \n";
                }

                if ($res && $res2) {
                    global $domain;
                    // ---------------- SEND MAIL FORM ----------------
                    // send e-mail to ...
                    $pwLink = $domain."/setAccountActive.php?ID=" . $UsersTabledoctorsID . "&email=". $email;
                    $pwLinkDeny = $domain."/doNotActivateAccount.php?ID=" . $UsersTabledoctorsID ."&email=". $email;
                    $to=$administratorsEmail;
                    $header="From: support@".$domain.".com";
                    $subject = 'Administrator : Doctor Request !';
                    $body = <<<EMAIL
Confirm Doctor $firstName $lastName Account ! \r\n";
Click on this link to activate your account ! $pwLink !\r\n"
Click to not activate this Account! $pwLinkDeny !\r\n"
EMAIL;

                } else {
                    echo json_encode(" Queries didnt finish \n");
                } 

            }
        }else{
            echo "email is not valid \n";
        }
    }
    $sentmail = mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
    if($sentmail){
//                        echo "an Email has been sent to the Administrator";
        $arr = array('result' => "true");
        echo json_encode($arr);
    } else {
        setInactive($UsersTabledoctorsID);
        echo "Cannot for unforseeable reasons verify your account";
    }

}else{
   echo "something not able to be set!\n"; 
}

?>
```

Comment: Also use try catch block

Comment: may be your response is not in json format

Comment: but it is, i echo a json array form my php with key 'result' value : true.

Comment: at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111) Json response not match show response and model class

Comment: That means Log your `result` and post

Comment: I've gotten this error before and it may be that the variable "result" doesn't contain valid JSON syntax. So yeah, do as the others are saying and display the contents of "results".

Comment: this is the output from my php  $arr = array('result' => true);
                        echo json_encode($arr); Is this not correct ? which for me outputs {"result":true}

Comment: @Aboogie "result" should be storing JSON text, something like: `"{"name":"John", "id":"12345"}"`

Comment: I did that, but oddly enough, response doesn't output anything. can't understand why. so Log.i("data", response.toString()); doesn't display anything.

Comment: Then there is no result retrieved.

Comment: @Aboogie actually I'm wrong, booleans don't need to be in quotes. My bad ha. I'm not 100% sure but it seems the bug is with your result variable.

Comment: @Ghost_Stark would say on the android code or the php, because I can't seem to see any errors, especially when I do see json output from php . should I post my php as well ? (I have posted it)

Comment: Can you show what is being returned after these lines: `Log.i("Im Here", "result");

                String result = response.toString();` ? The value of `response.toString()` to be specific.

Comment: Nothing is being displayed from response. what I am concerned with is that the url with the php should be running to the point that the queries should be happening but they are not occurring. which is weird.

Comment: Did you check your script by running it your browser

Comment: my scripts works if I give it all the inputs in the browser and it outputs the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because one of my files was commented before the start of the php script, the output of the php file was the comment which is not a JSON object, which is why my android was not understanding the input from the php return. I was able to delete the comment and I was able to receive from my php. Thanks all who tried to help !I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

before anything else.
I have some questions.

1. are you using your phone to connect to your local server (xampp)? if yes then SERVER_ADDRESS should be your IP Address.

OR if you're using a Virtual Device then SERVER_ADDRESS should be http://10.0.2.2/

2. you are posting a data.
   you should use $_POST[] not $_GET[] (though it will work BUT! proper coding techniques and practices should be used ALWAYS.
   AND
   `connection.setRequestMethod("POST");`

that's a POST so use $_POST[].

okay about the error.

> org.json.JSONException: Value

you will see this error BECAUSE.
the page you are posting to is not displaying a JSON/JSON Array Object.
meaning you have other texts in the page. like error display failed to connect or failed to register
or any other text beside the JSON/JSON Array.
the page SHOULD ONLY display JSON/JSON Array whether its a success or failure. you should display a JSON/JSON Array.

to avoid this.
when you successfully register echo a JSON/JSON Array text. (it has a success text in JSON format.)
if you failed to register STILL! echo a JSON/JSON Array text. (it has an failed text in JSON format.)

LIKE THIS

ONLY JSON Format SHOULD BE displayed

`if (Register True) {
     echo ["result":"true"]
} else {
     echo ["result":"failed"]
}`

then in your Android Code

`String isAuth = jsonObject.getString("result");
authenticate = isAuth.equals("true");`

AVOID any other text in where you are trying to post.

Comment: Hi, trying  echo ["result":"true"] in php gives me an error for the colon. I have tried numerous methods in php but it seems that none is working. anything else of why theres no response coming on the android side?

Comment: My other observation that is concerning me is that response is not receiving anything. any ideas on why this could be doing what it is doing ?